Unable to add a custom Quarkus resource in Kogito (404 Not Found)
A simple custom resource like this:
@Path("/")
@ApplicationScoped
public class IPPv2Resource {
    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}

Is correctly displayed in the swagger-ui page but when called Kogito returns (404 Not Found) error.
The documentation refers to creating custom resources starting from the code generated by the Kogito maven plugin, but I don't understand why I can't insert generic Quarkus custom resources anyway :-/
https://docs.kogito.kie.org/latest/html_single/#proc-kogito-custom-rest-endpoint-api_kogito-creating-running

Can you share how you call it from kogito ? have not used kogito before.
